# how to compare columns within dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I'm new to Python. I have a dataframe, and I want to filter it for the times values on Column A have come within 2% range of values on Column B.

So something like (i guess):

`df_[df_['B']*0.98<=df_['A']<=df_['B']*1.02]` #this prints an error

`len(df_[df_['B']*0.98<=df_['A']<=df_['B']*1.02])` #this prints an error

Comment: we need example for answer. can you provide example by text or code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write conditions separately, put them each in brackets and combine with the `&` operator. Try

```
df = df[(df['B'] <= df['A']*1.02) & (df['A'] <= df['B']*1.02)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## to create a columns in you data frame 'condition_verification'

```
import numpy as np
df('condition_verification')=np.where((df['B'] <= df['A']*1.02)& (df['A'] <= df['B']*1.02), True, False)
```